# Body's collision with Edges

Tags: c++, box2d, cocos2d-x

When my sprite collides with B2EdgeShape body "side walls".Body goes downward with gravity direction. How make possible that body bounces back horizontally when body collides with "side walls(b2edgeshape)"?

Comment: Please show us some code. Why is it going downward?

Answer (score 1):

*Actually i am not using "Restitution" in fixture definition of my body. Now body bounce back when collide with walls. :)*